Liquibase for Nodejs and Cassandra is failing with DatabaseException
I am trying to update cassandra from my node script. It works if I keep the jar files provided in classpath inside the lib folder of node_module liquibase but if I keep them outside in some other folder then I get below mentioned exception. The version of liquibase I am using is 4.28.0 and Cassandra 5.0. The search path shows the classpath included but I am not able to resolve this error.
const Liquibase = require('liquibase').Liquibase;

const myConfig = {
    changeLogFile: './changelog.xml',
    url: 'jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/cycling?compliancemode=Liquibase&localDatacenter=datacenter1',
    classpath: '/Users/admin/Downloads/lib/liquibase-cassandra-4.28.0.jar:/Users/admin/Downloads/lib/cassandra-jdbc-wrapper-4.13.0-bundle.jar',
    driver: 'com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver',
    logLevel: 'debug',
  }
const instTs = new Liquibase(myConfig);

instTs.status();
// instTs.updateSQL();
// instTs.update();

Here is my changelog.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">


    <changeSet id="1" author="xyz">
        <createTable tableName="test_table">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="text"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>


But I am getting below error
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL call current_schema: The Cassandra implementation does not support this method.
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:145)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:227)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:238)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:246)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:261)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:256)
    


As explained here, Liquibase only looks for extensions in 3 paths:

{liquibase_directory}/internal/lib
{liquibase_directory}/lib
{$pwd}/liquibase_libs

Is putting the liquibase-cassandra extension and driver jars into a liquibase_libs directory acceptable for your case?
With this structure:
.
├─ node_modules
│  └─ liquibase
│     └─ ...
├─ liquibase_libs
│  ├─ cassandra-jdbc-wrapper-4.13.0-bundle.jar
|  └─ liquibase-cassandra-4.28.0.jar
├─ changelog.xml
└─ liquibase_runner.js

and with liquibase_runner.js defined as follows:
const Liquibase = require('liquibase').Liquibase;

const myConfig = {
    changeLogFile: './changelog.xml',
    url: 'jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/cycling?compliancemode=Liquibase&localdatacenter=datacenter1',
    driver: 'com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver',
    logLevel: 'debug',
  }
const instTs = new Liquibase(myConfig);

instTs.status();

It should work as expected, without modifying the content of node_modules.
